# Is there a technique that’ll help me in writings

Tags: writing, learning-methods

my question is vividly clear in above.

My current technique is, If I see that the word does sound right from my perspective or from my previous readings, I write it down.
And sometimes I pronounce the word rightly because it come to me a lot and I write it down easily.

But It doesn’t work all the time.

I really appreciate it If someone could help me here or direct me to a link or a book, that will also help a lot

- How can I minimize my misspellings & writing mistakes? because I believe if I spell the word right, I’ll write it without any mistakes.
- think of me like a kid that he is bad in writing and you want to help him out.

Comment: I'm still not clear exactly what your current technique is. You say:"_If I __see__ that the word does __sound__ right from my perspective or from my previous readings, I write it down._" The bolded words in your sentence are contradictory. Do you mean: _If I __see__ that the word does __look__ right..._ (presumably the word that you yourself have written)? Or do you mean _If I __hear__ a word that I don't know how to spell...?_

Comment: Do you mean writing or spelling?

Comment: @Lambi see that I believe if I spell the word right, I’ll write it without any mistakes, so yeah I want to overcome both of these two problem,l.

Comment: Khalid, please tell us more about the writing aspect.  What is challenging for you?  What have you tried so far?  What type of writing would you like to get better at?

Comment: @aparente001 I have a problem in writing in general, and there’s a lot of words that I write them down wrongly so, I want to avoid that, because I have a goal If I graduate next year I’ll take the IELTS exam.

Comment: @Shoe **does sound** : It does not mean literally hearing a voice, it can be used to describe something or an impressions, like in my case; I meant that If I believe or my conscience said that it’s right I write it down, Did you get me or not? 

Comment: In the long term, the best way to improve your spelling is to read __a lot__. Collins Cobuild has a very full guide to English spelling that you might find useful, particularly if you know the International Phonetic Alphabet:https://www.amazon.co.uk/Spelling-Collins-Cobuild-English-Guides/dp/0003709507/ref=sr_1_fkmrnull_1?keywords=Collins+Cobuild+English+Guides+Spelling

Comment: @Shoe Thank you, My friend suggested me a book of David Crystal, its name is a little book of language and another one named Spell it out, did you read it?

Comment: I don't know the book you refer to, but I do know that David Crystal is an excellent linguist and teacher.

Comment: @Shoe Ok, thank you ether way for your help 

Answer (score 1):

Here are some suggestions for the spelling aspect:

- Work with MS Word or some similar software that allows you to turn on automatic spell checking.
- Choose an online or paper dictionary that you like and practice using it.  With an online dictionary, you can listen to the pronunciation; with both types, you can use the phonetic pronunciation key to figure out how a word is pronounced.
- There are some patterns in English spelling.  School children in English-speaking countries are taught some common patterns, such as "I before E except after C," and it might be helpful for you to familiarize yourself with these.
- Practice proofreading, to be more aware of spelling.  There are multiple ways to do this effectively, and I won't give you a broad list here, but I will suggest, for starters, that you take a look at the comment you left for user Lambie.  Check how this username is spelled, and what the last word of your comment looks like.